# How can I get Webpack to resolve my loader

Tags: webpack

I'm writing a Webpack loader and am trying to figure out how to get Webpack to "recognize" it after I've npm-installed the loader as a dependency. My loader is called `turbine-loader` and it's within an npm scope `@reactor`, therefore the package can be found in `node_modules/@reactor/turbine-loader`.

When I do `require('turbine-loader!../myFile');` from a module and then run webpack I get:

```
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'turbine-loader' in ...
```

If, in addition to the above, I put this in my webpack config:

```
resolveLoader: {
  alias: {
    'turbine-loader': require.resolve('@reactor/turbine-loader')
  }
}
```

It starts to work, but I don't want to force my loader consumers to do that if I don't need to. Could someone point me in the right direction? Maybe translate some [Webpack docs](https://webpack.github.io/docs/resolving.html#loaders) into plain English for me? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webpack just tries to `require` your loader by name. So if you try `require('turbine-loader!../myFile');` it will `require('turbine-loader')`, that is not defined.

Instead, you have to add your scope name to this require statement: 
`require('@reactor/turbine-loader!../myFile');`.

Btw, for me it looks pretty ugly and I'd prefer your option with `alias`:)

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thank you.